# Archlinux VLAN internet access virtualbox

Tags: arch-linux, virtual-machine, vlan, openstack

I need to configure Openstack on a Virtual Machine and for that I created an VLAN to support communication between controller and nodes. The problem is that I need internet access on this VLAN to download and install a few packages. My host computer is an Arch Linux distro and the guest (controller) is an Ubuntu Server Cloud.

I setted my VLAN this way:

```
$ ip link add link wlp2s0 name vlan.wifi type vlan id 100
$ ip addr add 10.17.17.0/24 brd 10.17.17.255 dev vlan.wifi   
$ ip link set dev vlan.wifi up
```

On my guest machine the IP is 10.17.17.200 but I can't even ping my host!

Answer (score 1):

The 10.17.17.0/24 is "network" IP not the usable one.